# How to enable direct access to my custom directory in Joomla site root?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I'm using Joomla, which is installed in site root, like:

`administrator/
components/
modules/
mycustomdir/
...`

... and for my custom purposes, I need to have one directory called "mycustomdir", which needs to be "independent" on Joomla site and public access to this directory will be enabled, so please, how can I tell Joomla "don't care about this directory and its content"?

Example: I need access to `http://www.myjoomlasite/mycustomdir`

I expect, that it will need any changes in .htaccess, unfortunatelly, I don't understand this file so much. I'm using SEF URL rewriting in Joomla and Apache web server is running on safe mode. Any ideas? Thanks for any help!

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
##Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On


## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage

RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#

## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a `.htaccess` file in your custom folder **mycustomdir**. The htaccess file should only have

```
RewriteEngine On
```

in it. By this you won't have to edit the original Joomla htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Usually, a folder can be accessible to everyone as long as you chmod it right and it doesn't conflict with your SEF rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think, that it has something to do with folder permissions. Permissions to mycustomdir are set to 755, the same, as other joomla folders. When I try to acces `mycustomdir` like `http://www.myjoomlasite/mycustomdir`, i will take joomla error 404: article was not found... but the folder and its contents really exist.